# Create copy of object (on inheritance)

Tags: c#

I have a method for creating copy of object

```
protected Node CreateCopy()
{
    return new Node(InputCount, OutpuCount, Name);;
}
```

And some child class like this:

```
public class SuperNode: Node { ... }

public class CoolNode: Node { ... }
```

Is there a way to automatically create copies of them?

(need type of child class not base)

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically create copies"?  Maybe give an example with incorrect results or syntax so it's clear what you're _trying_ to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically create copies of them ?

You can use the [`MemberwiseClone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) method inherited from `Object`:

```
protected Node CreateCopy()
{
    return (Node)MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Note that it will be a **shallow copy**, i.e. reference type members will be copied by reference, not cloned.

If you need a deep copy, you can serialize and deserialize the object (<strike>not very efficient</strike> very inefficient, and only works for serializable types), or use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Yes Worked :), so easy

Comment: "(need type of child class not base)" - this answer does not satisfy that.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Thomas Levesque's answer is great if you need a copy of the base class. But since you asked for the child type,</s> I'll just add this classic OOP suggestion:

```
class Node 
{
    protected int _num;
    protected string _text;

    public Node(int num, string text)
    {
        _num = num;
        _text = text;
    }

    public virtual Node Clone()
    {
        return new Node(_num, _text);
    }
}

class SuperNode : Node
{
    DateTime _superTime;

    public SuperNode(int num, string text, DateTime time)  :base(num, text)
    {
        _superTime = time;
    }

    public override Node Clone()
    {
        return new SuperNode(_num, _text, _superTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am doing this before I found this `(Node)Activator.CreateInstance(node.GetType())`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you are absolutely right, I'll blame the late hour for my mistake :)